# Images Shown in Popup Not in Table of ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, table, popup

I'm trying to export data from a map layer to an excel file. From ArcGIS Online I opened the layer using ArcGIS Pro. The images exist in AGOL, and can be seen from the pop-ups in Pro when individual points are clicked. But they aren't in the attribute table for some reason.

Does anyone know how I can get these points to show up in the table as well as the pop-up?

The image is stored as an attachment.

[image: attachment]

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify how they're being shown in the popup? Is it an *attachment* to the layer, or just a URL that the popup is configured to treat as an image path? If you could include a link to the layer or map, that would be helpful

Comment: Josh, I updated the original question with images of the pop-up and the field from the table in AGOL. The images exist as attachments. The data we normally use is a url and those display it the attribute tables properly. Field collection is new to me, so I'm not sure where the issue might be.

Comment: Even if I export the data from AGOL as an fgdb, getting an associated _ATTACH file, there is no link to the images themselves. Only the name of each image for all entries - Photo 1.jpg.